# Are there any phones that are produced with the tongue "cupped"?

Tags: phonetics

The book "Experiencing Speech: A Skills Based, Panlingual Approach to Actor Training" sets out to describe all the possible movements of the articulators. One of these is "cupping" the front of the tongue, or "making a kind of nest-shape in the front of your mouth where you might hold a blueberry or a grape". Now that I can do just fine, but the authors go on to say that the same thing can be done with the middle or back of the tongue body. I don't know how to begin to do that. Are there any linguistic sounds made with this tongue position? If so, maybe I can come at it by trying to copy them.

Comment: Hm... in preparing to swallow a pill, I think than I "cup" with the back of the tongue. Don't know if there are linguistically relevant sounds produced with that tongue position, at least I don't speak any language that has such kind of sounds.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica Thanks. For me that still seems to be pretty much at the front... maybe a tiny bit further back so I'll certainly work on it.